# Import some python3 modules in Python2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.x

Is there a way to import Python 3 modules into Python 2 scripts? I want to use some Python 3 modules in a Django application and haven't seen anything on the Internet. Any clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's really possible, no.  The same instance of the interpreter has to handle every module imported in a given app, so there's no obvious way to mix and match interpreters.  If you need to accomplish a discrete task with a Python 3 module, you could try making a command-line script to accomplish your task and then calling that script as a subprocess from your Python 2 app, but that would be awkward to say the least.

Note that I don't think there are really a whole lot of Python 3-only modules -- most modules at this point either support both versions, or only Python 2.

Comment: I got here for the opposite question (using a Python2 code on Python3). It is not possible then I assume for the same reason.